# HDRI environment texture assigned to background only shows a checkered background

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, image, hdri, world

I've just received a project which I imported into Blender with no issues.

However, whenever I go from *World* to *Color* then select *Environment Texture* and open my HDRI image which works with every other Blender project, all I see if a checkered gray and black background in rendered view.

Is it something to do with my viewport, or is it the project itself?
I tried editing the nodes and everything.

Answer (score 2):

In the render properties editor, disable Film > Transparent.

[image]